# Is there a term for an endomorphism defined up to conjugation by an automorphism?

Tags: category-theory, definition, abstract-algebra

Is there a standard term to designate the equivalence class of endomorphisms where two endomorphisms $\phi$ and $\psi$ are considered equivalent if there exists an automorphism $\alpha$ such that $\phi\alpha = \alpha\psi$?  Is there some theory about such equivalence classes?

**Example.** If $M$ is a free module over a commutative ring $R$ with a finite basis of size $n$, and $f$ is an endomorphism of $M$, then the *determinant* of $f$ can be defined by looking at the endomorphism
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^nM\stackrel{\bigwedge\nolimits^nf}{\longrightarrow}\bigwedge\nolimits^nM
$$
and canonically identifying it with an element of $R$, using the fact that the $R$-module $\bigwedge\nolimits^nM$ is free with a $1$-element basis. This definition of the determinant of $f$ can be generalized to obtain other invariants of $f$ by looking at the induced endomorphisms
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^kM\stackrel{\bigwedge\nolimits^kf}{\longrightarrow}\bigwedge\nolimits^kM
$$
for all $k$, and taking their equivalence classes up to conjugation by an automorphism.

Comment: I would call it a "conjugation class", but I doubt there's a standard term.

Comment: I think "conjugacy class" is fine. Your invariant packages the same information as the conjugacy class of $f$ itself, though. If you want a non-equivalence-class-based invariant you should take the trace, and then you get a coefficient of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, i've noticed too that it is not a very interesting invariant. I was trying to understand the determinant better.